# Vanishing webfonts in Google Chrome and WordPress 3.8

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, webfonts, font-awesome

I'm experiencing weird issue with Google Chrome 32.0.1700.107 m on Windows 7 64bit (but similar issue reported by friends on Mac and 32bit W7).

Fresh WordPress 3.8 with couple some plugins, default 2014 theme is active, no caching enabled.

In Dashboard (menu item icons, metaboxes icons) and on front-end where I have set to use webfonts (fontawesome for icons or some google webfont for text/headings) sometimes Chrome lost rendered look and display content with default font until I hover with cursor over text with "lost" font, and then Chrome re-render that text back in webfont font.

So, I load page, go to other tab, do something, then back to 1st tab and webfonts disappear, so I get squares for fontawesome icons and Arial/Helvetica/sans-serif for regular text.

You'll understand what I mean when you look on screenshot.

[image: screenshot of wrong and correct fontawesome icon rendering in WP Dashboard]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, this is a part of [this bug](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=236298) in Chrome. It's supposed to be ready to ship in the next update.